# Need To Modify My querySelectorAll Code For A Different Tag

Tags: javascript

My Code below was for videos in a video tag

```
function init() {
    for (var video of document.querySelectorAll('video')) {
      video.addEventListener('play', videoPlay, false);
      video.addEventListener('ended', videoEnd, false);
      video.addEventListener('timeupdate', videoTimeUpdate, false);
    }
  }
```

But how do I modify my above code to work with videos that are in the below code

```
<a data-type="iframe" data-src="/something/something.mp4"></a>
```

Comment: While you could *select* said elements easily enough with `a[data-type="iframe"]` etc, `<a>`s aren't `<video>` tags, they don't have `play` / `ended` events

Comment: so since they are not in a video tag I can't keep track of events such as length of the video, start and end?

Comment: It depends on how the tags' info is being used, and the code that does that isn't in the question

Comment: @ImASkuller I think you can do this using third party libraries, not using native methods.